# dpkg error when upgrading Vivaldi

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I got this error when I tried to update my Vivaldi browser.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up vivaldi-stable (2.8.1664.36-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package vivaldi-stable (--configure):
 installed vivaldi-stable package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vivaldi-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do I need to download something or edit a file in Ubuntu?

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f`. This might fix some dependency problems. Then update and reinstall vivaldi.

Comment: Do you have any commands that reinstall vivaldi?

Comment: First remove it using `sudo apt remove vivaldi-browser`. Then, supposing that you have downloaded the .deb file from [Vivaldi's website](https://vivaldi.com/download/), `cd` to the folder where you downloaded the .deb and then run `sudo apt install ./<vivaldi-deb>`, where `<vivaldi-deb>` is the actual name of the Vivaldi .deb package.

Comment: Or `sudo dpkg -r vivaldi-stable` then `sudo dpkg -i vivaldi...........deb` after you cd to the download directory. `vivaldi...........deb` is the name of the downloaded Vivaldi package

Comment: Thanks guys it solved this problem my savings in the browser is still left.

Comment: Also, you could try `sudo dpkg --configure vivaldi-stable` first and see if it works without removing.

Comment: Last question how can i mark this question as solved??

Comment: I wanna mark this as solved??

Comment: Please ask whoever helped solve your issue to write an answer below, then you can select it. Maybe @user3140225.

Comment: Okay user 4120225 how do i mark this question as solved??

Comment: @Raffa Installing a package with `apt` (or `apt-get`) actually runs `dpkg` under the hood, but has the additional benefit of taking care of package dependencies. Check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104592/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-and-dpkg).

Comment: Raffa can you post your solution too? It can be good for others when they search on this question so other people can try different solutions?

Comment: The **2.8.1664.36-1** package is most likely broken. I had the same issue earlier today, but when I tried just now I got **2.8.1664.36-2** instead and it installed just fine, without running any additional commands. I would add this post as a comment, but I'm not allowed yet, sorry.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, you can also add the Vivaldi stable and/or beta PPA to your system to get updates automatically. For the stable version, see https://help.vivaldi.com/article/manual-setup-vivaldi-linux-repositories/
The beta is the same, but substituting "beta" for "stable". I have used the beta for several years with no stability issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix any dependency problems by running:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

and update:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then, uninstall Vivaldi:

```
sudo apt remove vivaldi-browser
```

[Download](https://vivaldi.com/download/) the Vivaldi .deb package from the Vivaldi website and save it on your computer.

`cd` to the directory where you downloaded the .deb package and then install Vivaldi by running:

```
sudo apt install ./<vivaldi-deb>
```

In the above command `<vivaldi-deb>` is the actual name of the Vivaldi .deb package that you downloaded.